# Shell || Adding element to array separated by line not space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I am reading a file in a loop and there is string i got in each iteration. I need to add this element to array but in new line

i use the blow cmd ARRAYNAME+=$ELEMENTNAME

but what happens thet element is added to the last one but separated by " " instead of lines

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[-n "$line" ]];do
MAPPING=`echo $line | grep -e session -e sub | cut -d: -f3 | grep -i ","`
MAPPINGMAT+=("$MAPPING")
echo ${MAPPINGMAT[*]}
done < "$1"
```

output

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

but i need it to be

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: The line where you're assigning to `MAPPING` isn't valid I don't think, since `grep -i` needs a pattern, then you're not appending a full line to your array, and you're telling the loop to print the entire line on a single line in each iteration of the loop.  Use the `for` loop from my answer after the while loop to get it to print each element on its own line

Comment: grep -i is updated i missed it, i think for shall work but it will do much processing in big files as there is already while loop so i am trying to avoid it

Comment: If you print the entire array on a single line in every iteration of the loop, you're going to get the output you reported, there's no way to get different output unless you change how you're printing it.  The way you're adding it to the array isn't part of the problem for your output, the way you're producing the output is.  If you don't want a separate loop to print the array afterward, you could just `echo $MAPPING` within the `while` instead of printing the whole array each time

Comment: what you are saying is what i did. echo $MAPPING is done within while loop. i need only to add the output of MAPPING in a separate line in an array. reading the array shall be outside the while loop, here is just for tracking

Comment: So what about either my answer or deepmax's answer isn't working then?  If you're iterating over the array elements there isn't a concept of "lines" there, there are just elements, you can insert the lines where you like around the elements.  Both our answers sound like they're doing what you're asking for to me

Comment: thanks for your efforts but unfortunately it does not work as expected. can we adjust the array to change " " with new lines ?

I made this 
MAPPINGMAT=`(echo ${MAPPINGMAT[*]} | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq)`

but it didnot work fine

Comment: Again, the problem there is how you're trying to print the array, not with how things are stored in the array.  My `for` loop will show you how to print the array with each element on its own line, it's going to be very tough to get anything with `echo ${MAPPINGMAT[*]}` in it to put the elements on different lines, and probably isn't worth the effort (most likely).  If you don't want to iterate over the array to print it for some reason, I'll just have to wish you the best of luck finding another answer I guess

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesizes:

```
ARRAYNAME+=("$ELEMENTNAME")
```

To append an item to the end of the `ARRAYNAME`.

The reason you see below output

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

is that you're print the whole array in the loop in each iteration. Therefore `echo ${MAPPINGMAT[*]}` should not be in the loop. Replace it by a simple `echo "$MAPPING"`.

Answer (score 1):

With parens and quotes I get the entire line as an array element like so:

```
declare -a arr
while read -r line; do
    arr+=("$line")
done < input
```

Then I get each line in `arr` as seen in:

```
for(( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo ${arr[$i]}
done
```

Comment: my script as below
while IFS='' read -r line || [[-n "$line" ]];do
MAPPING=`echo $line | grep -e session -e sub | cut -d: -f3 | grep -i`
MAPPINGMAT+=("$MAPPING")
echo ${MAPPINGMAT[*]}
done < "$1"

Comment: It's very hard to follow that script in a comment, could you edit your question to include it?

Comment: In `bash` 4, this loop can be replaced with `readarray -t arr < input`.